# Deal with accents with r code in knitr (R/latex)

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I want to present a table that contains strings (sentences) in a PDF document generated with `knitr`.

My problem is that I'm french and most part of french's sentences contains at least one character like : "é", "è", "ç", "à", "ù", etc... And these characters are not printed if I write them directly.

I got all my sentences in a one-column `data.frame`.

I actually use `gsub` to replace these characters by their LaTeX usage. For exemple I just want to have `\'{e}` and not `é` in each sentences of my `data.frame`. To be the clearest that I can, there is a simple exemple of what I'm doing :

```
> varString <- "Salut, ça c'est une très jolie ligne pour essayer de gérer les accents"
> varString <- gsub("é","\\'{e}",varString)
> varString <- gsub("è","\\`{e}",varString)
> varString <- gsub("ç","\\c{c}",varString)
> varString
[1] "Salut, c{c}a c'est une tr`{e}s bonne ligne pour essayer de g'{e}rer les accents"
```

As you can see I don't have any backslash in my sentence after this code.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

PS : "Salut, ça c'est une très jolie ligne pour essayer de gérer les accents" = "Hi, this is a very good line to try to deal with accents".

Comment: You could use `cat` with `gsub` so the code would look like this: `cat(gsub("é","\\\\'{e}",varString), '\n')` and the otuput is `Salut, ça c'est une tres jolie ligne pour essayer de g\'{e}rer les accents`

Comment: Or use  `varString <- gsub("é","\\\\'{e}",varString) `,
  `varString <- gsub("è","\\\\`{e}",varString) `,
  `varString <- gsub("ç","\\\\c{c}",varString) ` and then `cat(varString, '\n')` to Concatenate and Print.

Comment: latex is perfectly able to deal with accented characters provided the right packages are included in the preamble

Comment: Thx Miha & baptiste !
I found a complete solution.

After doing what Miha said, I just had to print my xtable like that : `print(xtable(df),sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})`

Comment: @Smich7 Would you mind adding your solution as an answer? This could help future readers finding it. (You can also accept your own answer.)